# Best way to index faces with AWS Rekognition and associate them to the userId in MySQL

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, face-recognition, amazon-rekognition

I'm including facial recognition in my Electron app using Node.js and I would like to know if I'm doing the process correctly, as I was a little confused by some points in the documentation.

I'm using the `aws-sdk` library and I want that, when taking a picture of the user, my system searches for him in the database of faces registered in Rekognition and returns me who this user is - that is, **his `userId` in my MySQL database**.

I've already created a `Collection` called "Users" and I would like to know how to inform the `userId` to the `indexFaces` method. Initially, I intend to allow the inclusion of only one photo per user and I'm currently doing it like this:

```
const params = {
    CollectionId: 'Users',
    Image: { Bytes }, // The image in base64
    ExternalImageId: '1', // The userId in MySQL
    MaxFaces: 1,
    QualityFilter: 'HIGH'
};

Rekognition.indexFaces(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        return;
    }

    console.log(data);
});
```

The entire face registration process works normally and the code I use to search for the faces already registered is:

```
const params = {
    CollectionId: 'Users',
    Image: { Bytes }, // The image in base64
    MaxFaces: 1,
    FaceMatchThreshold: 99
};

Rekognition.searchFacesByImage(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err, err.stack);
        return;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < data.FaceMatches.length; i++) {
        console.log(data.FaceMatches[i].Face);
    }
});
```

If the consulted face is registered and found in the `Collection`, the value returned is:

```
{
  FaceId: 'b7506fc1-e8...',
  BoundingBox: {...},
  ImageId: 'e11d94c1-831...',
  ExternalImageId: '1', // `userId` in my MySQL as desired
  Confidence: 99.999...,
  IndexFacesModelVersion: '6.0'
}
```

My question is: am I associating the `userId` with the face correctly through the `ExternalImageId` property or should I do it in a more appropriate way? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the purpose of the `ExternalImageId` field -- it is for you to associate your own reference to the face. You are doing it correctly (assuming that the code works).